# Ubuntu 18.04 Emergency Mode

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I need to mount an external hard disk at a particular mount point since it keeps changing from **drivename** to **drivename1** and **drivename2** and so on on every mount.

So I followed [this tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1432413) and was able to successfully mount it to ***/media/external***

This is my **/etc/fstab** file now:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4667afae-8ccf-4223-9048-999c43794959 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7e6b60a3-e71e-4c41-a81d-ba853dce2ac7 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=F27A48007A47BFD9 /media/external ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000    0    0
```

I added the last line to mount it to ***/media/external***.

But when I start or restart my computer I am not getting my login screen.

Instead I am getting this:

> You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs,  "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl
>   default"  or ^D to try again to boot into default mode"<

When I remove the last line from **/etc/fstab** that I added then I am getting the login screen.

**Edit: Also is it possible to mount multiple external drives to same mount point /media/external?**

Added output of **lsblk -f**

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL   UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop1  squashfs                                              /snap/core/6673
loop2  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
loop3  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
loop4  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-characters/206
loop5  squashfs                                              /snap/postman/81
loop6  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop7  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop8  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop9  squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop10 squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop11 squashfs                                              /snap/core18/782
loop12 squashfs                                              /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop13 squashfs                                              /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop14 squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop15 squashfs                                              /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop16 squashfs                                              /snap/core/6405
loop17 squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop18 squashfs                                              /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop19 squashfs                                              /snap/core/6531
sda                                                          
├─sda1 ext4             4667afae-8ccf-4223-9048-999c43794959 /
├─sda2                                                       
└─sda5 swap             7e6b60a3-e71e-4c41-a81d-ba853dce2ac7 [SWAP]
sdb                                                          
└─sdb1 ntfs     mydrive F27A48007A47BFD9                     /media/user/mydrive2
sr0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92195/discussion-on-question-by-dragonborn-ubuntu-18-04-emergency-mode).